# How to process list of monos one by one?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a list as

```
List<Tuple3<Object1, Mono<List<Object2>>, Mono<List<Object3>>>>
```

And I need to write a method with signature as

```
private Mono<Dto> buildDto(List<Tuple3<Object1, Mono<List<Object2>>, Mono<List<Object3>>>> tuples) {...}
```

How I can follow all items in `tuples` list one by one to obtain values of Object1, Object2, Object3 without skipping no one of them?

I tried to execute

```
AtomicReference<Dto> dtoAtomic = new AtomicReference<>(buildEmptyDto());
return tuples.stream()
         .map(tuple3 -> {
             return Mono.zip(tuple3.getT2(), tuple3.getT3(),
                             (object2, object3) -> {
                                 Dto dto = dtoAtomic.get();

                                 dtoAtomic.set(dto);
                                 return dto;
                             });
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
         .stream()
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(Mono.just(dtoAtomic.get()))
```

But there is only one Mono.zip(...) could be obtained but I need to obtain all of tuples.

Comment: what `.findFirst()` do?  have to try with remove `.findFirst()` ??

Comment: Otherwise, there is no way to get some of the elements from the stream

Comment: why you need to use `stream()` ?

Comment: What are dto and Dto? Are they somehow related to Object1, Object2, Object3, object2, object3. It is not clear from the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `Flux.fromIterable(tuples)`